# SQL query to create ascending values within groups

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have the following table:

```
+----+--------+-----+
| id | fk_did | pos |
+----+--------+-----+
```

This table contains hundreds of rows, each of them referencing another table with `fk_did`. The value in `pos` is currently always zero which I want to change.

Basically, for each group of `fk_did`, the `pos`-column should start at zero and be ascending. It doesn't matter how the rows are ordered.

Example output (`select * from table order by fk_did, pos`) that I wanna get:

```
+----+--------+-----+
| id | fk_did | pos |
+----+--------+-----+
| xx |      0 |   0 |
| xx |      0 |   1 |
| xx |      0 |   2 |
| xx |      1 |   0 |
| xx |      1 |   1 |
| xx |      1 |   2 |
| xx |      4 |   0 |
| xx |      8 |   0 |
| xx |      8 |   1 |
| xx |      8 |   2 |
+----+--------+-----+
```

- There must be no two rows that have the same combination of `fk_did` and `pos`
- `pos` must be ascending for each `fk_did`
- If there is a row with `pos` > 0, there must also be a row with the same `fk_did` and a lower `pos`.

Can this be done with a single update query?

Comment: Should be pretty simple with a WITH clause and ROW_NUMBER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a window function:

```
update the_table
   set pos = t.rn - 1
from (
   select id, 
          row_number() over (partition by fk_id) as rn
   from the_table
) t
where t.id = the_table.id;
```

The ordering of `pos` will be more or less random, as there is no `order by`, but you said that doesn't matter.

This assumes that `id` is unique, if not, you can use the internal column `ctid` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If `id` is the PK of your table, then you can use the following query to update your table:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET pos = t.rn
FROM (
  SELECT id, fk_did, pos,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fk_did ORDER BY id) - 1 AS rn
  FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE mytable.id = t.id
```

`ROW_NUMBER` window function, used with a `PARTITION BY` clause, generates sequence numbers starting from 1 for each `fk_did` slice.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/99673/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a temporary table if `id` column is not unique):

```
create temp table tmp_table as 
select id, fk_did, row_number() over (partition by fk_did) - 1 pos
from table_name
```

And then truncate current table and insert records from the temp table